# Exception thrown at 0x69ABF340 when loading image with STBI_Image OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to load a .jpg image as a background, I loaded it with stbi_load however when i try to draw the texture i get the following error:
Exception thrown at 0x69ABF340 (nvoglv32.dll)
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0C933000. occurred

I tried changing the channels while loading the image, perhaps the image is not in rgb but rgba, with no success.

```
int width = 1280;
    int height = 720;
    int channels = 3;
    GLuint t;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char *image = stbi_load("bg.jpg",
        &width,
        &height,
        &channels,
        STBI_rgb);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &t);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The window should contain the texture specified, instead I get a white window with an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `STBI_rgb` indicates to load an generate a texture with 3 color channels. This causes that the image buffer (`image`) consists of 3 bytes per pixel.

But when you specify the two-dimensional texture image by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) then the specified format is `GL_RGBA`, which suggests 4 channels and so 4 bytes per pixel.
This causes that the data buffer is read out of bounds. Change the format parameter to `GL_RGB`, to solve that.

Further note, that by default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. Since the image has 3 color channel, and is tightly packed the start of a row is possibly misaligned.
Change the the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter to 1, before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`).

Further more, the texture is not (mipmap) complete. The initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. If you don't change it and you don't create mipmaps, then the texture is not "complete" and will not be "shown". See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).
Either set the minification filter to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

or generate mipmaps by [`glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) to solve the issue.

e.g.:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the exception. However, I now get a black window.

Comment: @WillRobert I've extended the answer, probably  `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)` is missing.